# Qual a diferença entre aspas duplas e aspas simples em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Contexto**
Em PHP, há uma diferença entre o uso de aspas simples e duplas. Neste caso, aspas simples são para "`strings` comuns", e aspas duplas, utilizadas quando se quer processar a `string` (concatenar, por exemplo).

**Pergunta**
Existe alguma diferença entre o uso de <kbd>"</kbd> e <kbd>'</kbd> para `strings` em Javascript? Há alguma mudança no desempenho, ou conflitos com `use strict`, por exemplo?

**Exemplo**

```js
alert('foo'); // Aspas simples
alert("bar"); // Aspas duplas
```

Comment: Em linguagens em que aspas simples e duplas são intercambiáveis eu gosto de usar uma convenção pra dizer quando se usa aspas de cada tipo. Uma convenção que eu gosto é aspas simples pra strings "internas" ao sistema e aspas duplas pra coisas que vão ser mostradas para o usuário.

Comment: É questão de gosto mesmo. Aspas simples fazem você economizar um shift.

Comment: Podem ser utilizadas aspas do mesmo tipo sem gerar nenhum conflito, se fizer assim "\"conteudo\"", o resultado será esse "conteudo" na saida de uma função, ou seja, a barra invertida com as aspas juntas fazem o navegador identifica-las diferente, mesmo sendo iguais.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Não há diferenças do ponto de vista de programação, mesmo utilizando Strict Mode (`"use strict;"`)

Como apontado pelo Carlos André, uma abordagem é você poder colocar aspas simples dentro da string ou o oposto:

```
alert('Ola "Mundo"');
alert("Ola 'Mundo'");
```

No entanto, se você estiver utilizando JSON, as strings em JSON utilizam aspas duplas. Obviamente, várias bibliotecas também suportam aspas simples, mas utilizar aspas simples para strings não está em conformidade com os [padrões de JSON](http://json.org/json-pt.html).

Answer (score 11):

Não existe nenhuma diferença.

A única vantagem de utilizar aspas duplas é que você pode colocar aspas simples dentro da string ou o oposto:

```
var str = "Lorem 'ipsum' dolor";
var str = 'Lorem "ipsum" dolor';
```

Answer (score 1):

Embora não exista uma regra de quando se utilizar os dois tipos de aspas, o mais comum é o `atributo herdar aspas duplas (")` e os `argumentos do mesmo aspas únicas (')`, caso deseje é possivel utilizar o mesmo tipo de aspas, sem gerar erro algo, basta seguir o modelo abaixo.

`\'conteudo\'` ou `\"conteudo\"` desta forma o `'\'a\''` irá retornar em uma função como `'a'`, sem dar erro, contendo o mesmo tipo de aspas o atributo e  seus parâmetros. O `use strict` não é afetado por esse tipo de utilizações.

**Exemplo**

```
<script>
var teste = { a: function(a){ console.log(a.name); } }
teste.a({name:'\'a\''});
</script>
```