# Como usar as aspas duplas e simples?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Vamos imaginar o seguinte **exemplo**:

```
$color = "red";
echo ("<button onclick='change_background("/red"/);'>$color</button>");
```

O que devo usar quando tenho 3 niveis usando o exemplo em
**`change_background("/red"/);`**?

Eu queria saber como funciona quando estão dentro uns dos outros tipo `"primeiro nivel 'segundo nivel \'terceiro nivel\' '"`

Comment: O echo não é uma função, logo o parentese é opcional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você precisa ler estas duas perguntas (e respostas):

- [Qual a diferença entre aspas duplas e aspas simples em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3755/101)
- [Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4652/101)

Então é bom saber que pode, na maioria das situações, estabelecer um padrão para evitar confusão entre o código PHP e JS. Assim evitando o caractere de *escape* (a `\`).

Este caractere só é necessário quando eles se confundem. Por exemplo. Você está usando aspas duplas no texto do PHP. E dentro tem código HTML com aspas duplas também. Estas aspas ali no HTML vai fechar o texto do PHP e não é o que você quer. Então usa `\"` ou `\'`, assim o interpretador PHP saberá que aquelas aspas fazem parte do texto e não é o indicador que ele está sendo encerrado.

É chato fazer isto,  então é melhor escolher um tipo para o código de uma linguagem e o outro tipo no outro código.

Eu costumo usar aspas simples no PHP e duplas no HTML, a não ser nos raros casos específicos que isto pode se mostrar pior.

Quando tem código JS dentro do HTML, não tem muito jeito, tem que voltar usar o mesmo tipo de aspas que o HTML já usou ou que o PHP já usou e tem que usar o caractere de *escape*.

Por isto é melhor deixar código JS fora do HTML, tanto quanto possível.

Note que no seu código exemplo não está usando a barra invertida que é o *escape*. Na descrição do problema dos níveis, você usou corretamente.

[Caracteres de escape do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

[Caracteres de escape do JS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: mas eu queria saber como funciona quando estão dentro uns dos outros tipo "primeiro nivel 'segundo nivel \'terceiro nivel\'         '"

Comment: Eu estava terminando a resposta, veja se a conclusão ajuda. Eu até já tinha dado a introdução a isto. Tem algo mais que queira saber?

Comment: sendo assim o meu terceiro nivel está correcto?

Comment: Sim, está, eu prefiro intercalar, para ficar mais visível. Prefiro mais ainda evitar que tenha o terceiro nível.

Comment: Perfeito obrigado  :)

Answer (score 6):

O problema está nas suas barras, que estão invertidas.

Teste assim:

```
$color = "red"; 

echo ("<button onclick='change_background(\"red\");'>$color</button>");
```

Altere as barras de "/" para "\".

Answer (score 4):

Para resolver este tipo de problema costumo usar a função `sprintf`, presente no `PHP`. Pois assim posso escrever o bloco de texto normalmente.

#### PHP

```
$button = '<button onclick="change_background(%s);">%s</button>';
$color = 'red';
echo sprintf($button, "'{$color}'", $color);
```

#### JS

```
if (!String.prototype.sprintf) {
  String.prototype.sprintf = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}

var str = '<button onclick="change_background({0});">{1}</button>';
var color = 'red';
echo str.sprintf('"'+color+'"', color);
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format#answer-4673436)

Comment: É mais facil vc trocar o `sprintf()` que não imprime nada ele é adequado para fazer atribuições em variáveis, pelo `printf()`.