# Existe diferença entre usar barra invertida e simples?

Tags: php, string

Quero saber se quando se trata de fazer *upload* de um arquivo, tipo assim:

```
$destino = 'imagens/' . $novoNome;
```

Existe diferença entre `imagens/` e `imagens\`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende do contexto. Se for para uso como separador de diretórios o PHP abstrai isto e usa o que for mais adequado para a plataforma que está rodando. Não quer dizer que sempre funcionará como o esperado, mas em geral é assim. Costuma-se preferir usar a barra normal e não a invertida. Há quem prefira usar [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) ou até mesmo criar funções para abstrair o uso de *paths*.

Se for apenas uma *string* normal faz muita diferença em alguns casos. A barra normal é só uma barra, a barra invertida é um indicar que o próximo caractere é especial, então um `\n` é pular uma linha, `\t` é uma tabulação ou `\\` é quando deseja que a barra invertida seja usada como caractere normal. Mas isto depende se está usando [aspas simples ou dupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89812/101), no caso da simples usada a única vez que a invertida faz algo diferente é quando usa `\'` para indicar que não está encerrando a *string* e sim quer que um apóstrofe seja usado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).