# Aspas simples tem diferença de aspas duplas?

Tags: php, css

Gostaria de saber se aspas simples `''` tem diferença de aspas duplas `""`, tanto no `PHP` quanto nas `div`

Comment: Aqui você pode tirar um pouco sua dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89812/como-usar-as-aspas-duplas-e-simples