# No HTML e CSS devo usar Aspas Simples ou Aspas Duplas? Existe alguma recomendação?

Tags: html, css, navegador-de-internet

Recentemente reparei que o editor de texto que uso me da um "alerta" caso eu use aspas simples `' '` no HTML.

Abaixo seguem dois exemplos, um usando Aspas Simples no corpo do documento no `<body>`, e outro usando Aspas Simples dentro do `<head>`. Repare que onde há Aspas Duplas não tem nenhum "alert".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Resalto que o Browser consegue interpretar o código, mesmo estando com Aspas Simples! Mesmo com elas o código é renderizado direitinho na tela!

---

E para confundir ainda mais me parece que no CSS não há problema em usar Aspas Simples ou Duplas... Repare que na imagem tem Aspas dos dois tipos misturadas e mesmo assim não tem problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Então ficaram as dúvidas:**

- Existe uma boa prática no uso das Aspas no HTML e CSS?
- O navegador não vê diferença entre os tipos de aspas e posso usar a que eu achar melhor?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244031/8063

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, não, sim.

Não existe uma boa prática estabelecida, use a que te agradar melhor. Não há diferenças para o navegador desde que a forma como utilizar não quebre a sintaxe do HTML e gere resultados inesperados (mas aí o erro foi seu, não do navegador) e sim, pode usar o que preferir.

Conforme [especificação da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2), você pode usar aspas duplas, aspas simples e até mesmo aspas nenhuma. Não faz diferença.

> *By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39)*

Traduzindo, por padrão o SGML (*Standard Generalized Markup Language*) requer que todos os valores de atributos sejam delimitados por aspas duplas (caractere 34 da tabela ASCII) ou aspas simples (caractere 39 da tabela ASCII).

> *In certain cases, authors may specify the value of an attribute without any quotation marks. The attribute value may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45), periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons (ASCII decimal 58). We recommend using quotation marks even when it is possible to eliminate them.*

Traduzindo, em certos casos autores podem especificar o valor de um atributo com nenhuma aspa. Neste caso o valor do atributo pode possuir apenas letras (a-zA-Z), dígitos (0-9), hífens, pontos, sublinhados e dois pontos. A mesma especificação recomenda, inclusive, evitar esta prática sempre que possível - sem maiores motivos.

Então, use o que preferir. Provavelmente recomenda-se sempre usar ou simples ou duplas para caso um dia seja exigido uma delas você não precisar corrigir o seu código.

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-red">Com aspas duplas</div>
<div class='text-red'>Com aspas simples</div>
<div class=text-red>Sem aspas</div>
```

Cita-se ainda que é permitido o uso de ambos justamente para permitir utilizar os caracteres em seus valores, bem como acontece com outras linguagens. Se você definir o valor com aspas duplas, a aspa simples não quebrará a sintaxe; a recíproca é verdadeira.

Mas em todos os casos você pode representar o caractere com seu código sem interferir na sintaxe do HTML. Por exemplo, para utilizar as aspas duplas em um valor definido por aspas duplas você pode fazer:

```html
<a title="Valor do &#34;title&#34; com aspas duplas">Veja o title</a>
```

O `title` da âncora será `Valor do "title" com aspas duplas` mesmo que foi definido com aspas duplas.

**Mas por que o editor reclamou das aspas simples?**

Deve ser configuração interna do editor afim de manter a consistência no projeto. É mais comum utilizarem as aspas duplas e provavelmente o editor esteja configurado para utilizar as aspas duplas. Quando utilizado as aspas simples ele emitirá este **alerta** (não um **erro**) de que talvez você deveria reconsiderar o seu código. Se em todo o projeto é utilizado as aspas duplas, por que ali usar aspas simples? Provavelmente é configurável e se você quiser utilizar as aspas simples, poderá fazê-lo e a mensagem aparecerá sempre que usar aspas duplas.

Comment: Cara sem aspas nenhuma foi novidade para mim, Mas realmente é tipo o Fiat 147 do Maniero... Funciona, mas não deveria :D

Answer (score 4):

A norma comum, o padrão usado em HTML é a presença de aspas dúplas (") entre cada atributo de um elemento, como `style`, `src` em imagens. É puramente uma norma.

É preferivel que se use a mesma simbolização em ambos para facilitar manutenção. Em CSS e HTML, é usado aspas duplas, mas em JavaScript e Typescript o usual é usar apóstrofe/aspas simples (') para indicar strings.

Em resumo, é tudo uma norma.

Por exemplo, é melhor você usar " em HTML/CSS para escrever comandos de JS nas tags e ter uma diferenciação clara, ao invés de fazer uso de escape characters.