# Form enviando NULL para o PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho um FORM que deveria enviar para o PHP o ID do usuario, mas o PHP recebe null.

HTML: 
(o `<?=$individuo["ID"]` está retornando o id corretamente)

```
<form name="alterar" action="alterar.php" method="POST">
    input type="text" name="id" value=<?=$individuo["ID"]?>>
    <input type="submit" name="Editar" value="editar"> 
</form>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php 

        var_dump($_POST["ID"]);
    ?>
```

Comment: coloca entre aspas, e tá faltando um < no input

Comment: @CypherPotato Só comentando: as aspas ali é opcional. Para o HTML `value=1` é perfeitamente válido. Pode ler mais em [No HTML e CSS devo usar Aspas Simples ou Aspas Duplas? Existe alguma recomendação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/357362/5878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Mesmo os indices do $_POST são Case Sensitives, ou seja, o certo seria o name ser "ID"

```
<form name="alterar" action="alterar.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="ID" value=<?=$individuo["ID"]?>>
<input type="submit" name="Editar" value="editar"> 
</form>
```

Ou Alterar o php, desta forma:

```
<?php 

    var_dump($_POST["id"]);
?>
```

Comment: Fico impressionado com, nao importa o tempo que voce programe, o problema sempre vai ser algo bobinho assim. O senhor salvou minha noite, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Esqueceu de colocar o `echo` e usa aspas simples.

Coloca teu código assim:

```
<form name="alterar" action="alterar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $individuo['ID'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="Editar" value="editar"> 
</form>
```